# Unable to Contact Destination Server while Copying file to another library

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2007, document-library

We are currently unable to copy files (Send To -> Another Location or Existing Copies).

I did my part of research on google about this error and didn't found much. So to skip all the did you try this or that, I'll list exactly what we are trying to do, what is the result and what are to solutions I have atempted, all in vain.

First, our SharePoint server is a MOSS 2007.

So we try to take a document in the following list :

> `http://sharepoint.local.com/Sites/EPARGNECOLLECTIVE/Priv%20Prliminaire`

As you can see for the URL this site is the root of the site collection, so yes I have a root site for my site collection.

And I'm trying to send it to this list :

> `http://sharepoint.local.com/Sites/EPARGNECOLLECTIVE/IDW/gap/`

As you can see they are in the same site collection, but in a sub site.

> *Note : The original test was to send it to a specific folder, but sending it to the root of the library doesn't work either so let's
>   focus on that.*

To send it there, we select the original file and in the drop down menu select : **Send To** then **Another Location**. In the folowing screen I **type** the URL (*so no it's not because I copy pasted it and bring random stuff with it*).

> Note : The original action was to select **Send To** then **Existing Copies** and pick the copy that was already existing, so it works in
>   the past, and the pas wasn't that far we are talking August 22th.

Every time the action could not be completed and the only error I receive is this :

> Unable to Contact Destination Server

So a little of research on google showed up that may be the problem was security related and that the user running the Application Pool required right in the list. So I added the service account to the list with full access. No luck, no change still the same error. Right now the user acount *still* has the rights.

Next I searched in SharePoint logs to see if there was more information. In fact there was. Every time I tried to copy two error messages showed up.

> Access to this Web site has been blocked. Please contact the administrator to resolve this problem.

and

> Possible mismatch between the reported error with code = 0x81070967 and message: "Access to this Web site has been blocked.
>   Please contact the administrator to resolve this problem." and the
>   returned error with code 0x81020071.

Did some digging with theses erros and I founded that may be my site collection was blocked for a backup. So I uses **stsadmin** and run the folowing command line :

> **stsadm.exe -o getsitelock -url `http://sharepoint.local.com/Sites/EPARGNECOLLECTIVE/IDW/gap/`**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally founded what caused "**Send To -> Other existing copies**" to gave the "**Unable to contact destination server**" error.

I had an other site collection that was locked. The other site collection had the url of : `http://sharepoint.local.com`

Looks like it causes some problems since it was part of the url of the source and the target site collection I was using that was : `http://sharepoint.local.com/Sites/EPARGNECOLLECTIVE`

After unlocking that web collection, the feature started working.

Answer (score 0):

I have MOSS env too ..Try this...Navigate to SiteAction -Site Settings - Site Administration-Content and Structure then in that navigate to the Source choose the File that you would like to Copy on the Actions tab select Copy(Note Copy will make a copy at the destination and Move will move it for ever to the Destination) choose the destination subsite and the List and it should be Copied/Moved..Try this or maybe even might have even tried this.

Good Luck

Comment: I don't have the Manage Content and Structure in my site collection, probably because I don't have the Office SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure. And since the features worked last week and that feature was never activated, and we are talking about production server I just can't activate it and hope nothing crashes.

Comment: Try creating a new Site Collection and enable that feature on that and test it..That feature will never crash anything, try that good luck